# IDE's Java runtime (1.8u66) is outdated - this may cause stability issues. Please update to 1.8.0u112 or newer while opening PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: pycharm, centos6, java-runtime-compiler

I recently downloaded PyCharm Community Edition for automation development using Python3. When i launch pycharm i am getting following alert in Event Log to upgrade my Java runtime.
I am using Centos 6.7 and how can i update my Java runtime?

I have tried switching Java runtime on PyCharm but since i have not upgraded the java runtime on my machine i am not able to select the lates runtime on PyCharm.

Error:
IDE's Java runtime (1.8u66) is outdated - this may cause stability issues. Please update to 1.8.0u112 or newer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the latest JDK, download it from: [Download latest JAVA JDK HERE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Then ---> Start the IDE, use Help | Find Action (Ctrl+Shift+A or Cmd+Shift+A on Mac), type "Switch IDE Boot JDK" select it, press Enter.